# Sortable not working properly

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

why when I turn items in shelf, item position is shifted to the end?
How to fix it?

Many thanks

Demo: http://dev.iteams.visionscms.com/manage.html

I think something in this lines...
`.draggable({
...
//                        containment: '.container',
//                        connectToSortable: '.shelf ul',
...`

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/danoman7/FTyXk/16/